# Track click event with Google UA

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I would like to track clicks on my accordions. Every panel has a unique ID. Below is just an example with 3 panels. This is my html:

```
<div id="accordion">
<div class="default" id="c35967">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>header 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="text trigger" style="display: none;">
        <p>text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="default" id="c34968">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>header 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="text trigger" style="display: none;">
        <p>text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="default" id="c27969">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>header 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="text trigger" style="display: none;">
        <p>text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JS (using jQuery):

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
//From http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/
$('#accordion div .header').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('#accordion div .header').removeClass('active');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.trigger').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('active');

        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');

        // Alter the hash value for easy linking
        if ($(this).parent().attr('id') != '') { 
            window.location.hash = 'panel' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
        }
     }        
 });
```

I would like to track the click event and transferred the unique ID of the panel to Google UA. And if the header can come along to Google UA to make it more manageable it would be perfect.

I belived that the tracking should be in this part:

```
    // Alter the hash value for easy linking
    if ($(this).parent().attr('id') != '') { 
        window.location.hash = 'panel' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
    }
```

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of Event Listener:

```
$('#accordion div .header').click(function() {   
    var eCat = "UX";
    var eAct = "Slideshow Click";
    var eLab = $(this).parent().attr("id") + " - " + $(this).find("h3").text();

    ga('send', 'event', eCat, eAct, eLab); 
});
```

Comment: it looks very simple. I'll try it. Do you have any idea how to send the header (<h3>XXXX</h3>)? Somethiing like this: var eLab = $(this).parent().attr("id") + 'XXXX';